# To infinitive VS bare infinitive

Tags: passive-voice, to-infinitive, active-voice, bare-infinitives, semantics

> **He  made  me  laugh**(active)
>
> **I was  made to laugh by him(passive voice)**

In the active voice  made is  followed by personal object and bare infinitive.

But in the passive voice made is followed by to infinitive.

What is the reason for the use of the  bare infinitive and to  infinitive  in different  voice?

I know that the verb **make** is followed by bare infinitive.

What  is  the rule applied  here?

If we use bare infinitive in the pasive voice, does the sentence become  wrong?

No  grammar book  has given any explanation  about this

Comment: It's a rule of grammar that "make" takes a bare infinitival complement, while in the passive it takes a _to_ infinitival. I don't know why this is the case; I suppose it's just the way the language has evolved.

Comment: What BillJ said. Congratulations! You've found an inconsistency in English,. I observe, though, that it wasn't always inconsistent: in Early Modern English, _make_ could take a "to" infinitive in the active - Psalm 23 in the King James Version (1611) contains "He maketh me to lie down in green pastures". This construction is now obsolete, though.